Blazor 8 Timer Table update without button click
I have a Blazor 8 with InteractiveServerMode. I have a table that shows jobs to be done by a server. The jobs might be added every 20 sec (or an other program checks if there are any new jobs added and the adds them to the db if there are every 20 sec).
I have tried to add a timer to the Blazor site to make it recheck the db for updates. But I can't get the table to update.
Everything works without the timer (the table gets filled with the jobs that are in the db) but if I add a timer the table don't get filled.
html:
@if (jobsToDo.Count == 0)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table is-hoverable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Est. Time</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var job in jobsToDo)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@job.Id</td>
                    <td>@job.Name</td>
                    <td class="columns m-0">
                        <div class="column is-narrow p-0">@job.Priority</div>
                        <div class="column p-0">
                            @if (job.Priority != 1)
                            {
                                <span class="icon" @onclick="() => UpdatePriorityUp(job)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></span>
                            }
                            @if (job.Priority != jobsToDo.Count)
                            {
                                <span class="icon" @onclick="() => UpdatePriorityDown(job)"><i class=" fas fa-arrow-down"></i>

                                </span>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>@job.EstimetedTime</td>
                    <td>@job.Owner</td>
                    <td @onclick="() => DeleteJob(job)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

C# code:
private List<JobToDo> jobsToDo = new List<JobToDo>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Timer();
    }

private void Timer()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(20000);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await GetJobsToDo();
        timer.Start();
        timer.AutoReset = true;
    }
private async Task GetJobsToDo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in getjob");
        using JobsContext db = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        jobsToDo = await db.JobToDo.ToListAsync();
        jobsToDo = jobsToDo.OrderBy(j => j.Priority).ToList();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

The "in getjob" text is printed to the Console every 20 sec, so the timer is working but the table is not rendered at all.
I have:
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]

At the top of the file.
If I add the GetJobsToDo() to OnInitializedAsync() the table is filled. @onclick events update the table as well.
What are I missing?? Please help!
UPDATE:
I have looked at the Question that is similar and tried:
private void Timer()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(20000);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => 
        {
            await GetJobsToDo();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        };
        timer.Start();
        timer.AutoReset = true;
    }

With no change. The Console.Writeline text is printed to the Console but the table is not rendered.

This question is similar to: How can I use I timer in my Blazor server app, to perform an action periodically?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

the table is not rendered at all or it takes a long time to be rendered ? based on your codes ,the table would only be rendered after 20 more seconds when the timer elapsed

@RuikaiFeng I can se that the Console.WriteLine("in getjob") text is printed to the Console but the table is not rendered.

@DA I have tried the UPDATE I part of that question without any change with rendered

Check jobsToDo.Count after the loading, use a WriteLine

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, so here's a working version of your code implemented in the Weather page.
@page "/weather"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private List<WeatherForecast>? forecasts;

    // Move out to a class level variable.
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate streaming rendering
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToList();

        Timer();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }

    private void Timer()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await GetJobsToDo();
        timer.Start();
        timer.AutoReset = true;
    }

    private async Task GetJobsToDo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in getjob");
        forecasts?.Add(new() { Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now), TemperatureC = 0, Summary = $"Added at {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}" });
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}

Note:
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]

is redundant. The page is InteractiveServer.
The timer instance is elevated to the class level so it can be disposed correctly.
The component implements IDisposable to dispose the Timer.

Yeey this worked.... Moving the timer out to a class level seams to have done the trick. I tried that in the beginning without it working but I must have missed something else then. Thank you so much :)
